# Safari fails to load MP4 videos

Tags: javascript, safari, mp4

Latest Safari v11.0 fails to play videos with MP4s which have been set dynamically via JavaScript. But that works fine on Chrome, Edge and FF.

My code sets the `src` element pointing to a MP4 resource like that:

```
<video class="replay" autoplay="true" autostart="true" autobuffer="true" playsinline="true" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" controls="controls" style="" preload="auto" muted="true">
    <source src="https://videomail.io/videomail/11e7-ad5a-4b14b680-a354-934ec5b49c33/preview/type/mp4/x-videomail-site-name/videomail.io/videomail.mp4?1507598907103" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The problem is that Safari highlights this in red under the Network tab:

[image]

Under Request & Response (on right) it says it got cancelled. Why?

Plus under Request Headers I see: `Range bytes=0-1`. Seems weird. Although I curled that resource and looks fine, can be downloaded completely.

Tried many different changes, all fail. Not sure if it's an nginx issue, a bug in my JS code or a Safari thing. Any clues very welcome.

Very easy to reproduce:

1. In Safari, go to [www.videomail.io](https://www.videomail.io)
2. Start recording a video
3. Click on preview and no video comes up (works fine on Chrome)

Comment: Safari, or rather iOS in general expects video's binary data to not being served as a whole file.. it expect it in smaller sized, thus the `Range bytes=0-1`.

Comment: What does `video.canPlayType("video/mp4")` log at `console`?

Comment: @guest271314 that returns me a "maybe"

Comment: @MichaelHeuberger Have no experience using safari. Cannot test the code. `"maybe"` indicates the media should be be able to be played. Have you tried setting the `.src` of `<video>` to a `Blob URL` representation of media resource?

Comment: Seems like a problem between your nginx and Safari. I was able to load the same video file once saved on my localhost. Also, @guest271314 proposed workaround should work: when passing a blobURI from the fetched resource, it works well.

Comment: thanks guys - very hesitant to use blobURI here. any ideas what nginx config can mess with this?

Comment: ah - think i fixed it with better flags in expressjs' sendFile() function. will update my question. sorry to have "wasted" your time but you definitely helped me eliminating possible causes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---- FINAL SOLUTION ----

Fixed this myself by using following in the express.js controller code:

```
  res.sendFile(file, {
    lastModified: false,
    acceptRanges: true,
    cacheControl: false
  }, function (err) {
    if (err && err.code !== 'ECONNRESET') {
      next(err)
    }
  })
```

Comment: I'm curious to know what your controller code looked like before the fix. I'm currently having trouble trying to use `fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res)` without success. Same issue where Safari v11 doesn't like the served mp4.

Comment: before the fix, i was just using `res.sendFile(file, function (err) { ...` without those three crucial flags.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `X-pad: avoid browser bug` response header fixes the issue for me.